# How can i change a textView's content each day at specific time automatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a List of quotes and i want to show a random quote from that List each day in the morning automatically. I want to implement that in a TextView inside a fragment. I played with the Calendar class but it doesnt work automatically because the instance is created only when the user opens the app. Any suggestion or help to do that with kotlin please!

Comment: How are you displaying the TextView anyways if your app isn't open?

Comment: What i meant is when the user opens the app for exemple at 00:01 he should get a different quote from what he got at 23:59.

Comment: You can get current time using Calendar class. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate start a timer (https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer) with scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
set delay to the time until 00:00. And the period to one day. In the task you can update the textview. Hope that helps. If you have trouble with implementing this, I would be happy to help you.

Here is the code. Havent tested it but should work.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Timer t = new Timer();
    final long ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        updateTextView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // construct tomorrow midnight
        Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
        date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        date.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateTextView();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, date.getTime(), ONE_DAY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        t.cancel();
        t.purge();
    }

    private void updateTextView() {
        //... do your update here
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you didn't see that i wanted it in kotlin and in a fragment but thank you anyway i will try to change it to kotlin.